# Creating keys that are not unique in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

How to create a reference from table A to table B to ensure that B.b column has all the values in column A.a, when A.a has duplicates and B.b has duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your question, but I am not sure a reference will work. You may need to run a query to sync the tables initially (you said it needs “all the values”), and then use a trigger to create new rows in B as rows are inserted/updated/deleted from A.

```
INSERT INTO B (b) SELECT DISTINCT A.a FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.b = A.a WHERE B.b IS NULL
```

I may be way off on this as I am not 100% sure I understand your issue. Sorry if that is the case.

Comment: I need to validate that a table contains all the values from another table. But each table could have the value multiple times (non unique key on first table, non unique foriegn key on second). is that possible?

Comment: In all honesty, it sounds like your data model may benefit from some normalization. Would you be willing to share the schema for both tables? I am not sure if you have the luxury of changing things though. 